# what are the components of the variable assignment log entry

Tags: apex, debugging

on finest, my log entry looks like this:

09:30:19.490 (8458283328)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[231]|this|{"c":"0x2980752a","tasks":"0x6e159af1"}|0x3de7ae9e

It's a variable assignment in object.method().
I'm trying to figure out if 0x3de7ae9e is the pointer address for the object.  Hopefully it is, and I can tell which instance of an object a method is firing on.  Otherwise, is there a way to tell?  Also tasks is a List of tasks.  is 0x6e159af1 the address for this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 09:30:19.490 (8458283328)

The time at evaluation of that line of code.

> VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT

The specific op-code being evaluated.

> [231]

The line which is being executed.

> this

The target object. `this` means the current object context, it can also be a symbol, such as `myClass.myProp`.

> {"c":"0x2980752a","tasks":"0x6e159af1"}

The value being assigned to the property.

> 0x3de7ae9e

The heap address of the object being used.

---

> I'm trying to figure out if 0x3de7ae9e is the pointer address for the object.

Yes, as mentioned above.

> Also tasks is a List of tasks. is 0x6e159af1 the address for this list?

Yes, it is. If you open the log viewer in the Developer Console, you can use the Debug > Switch Perspective > Debug (Predefined) perspective to see the variables in memory, search by the memory address/pointer, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I'm looking on confirmation for.  It's too bad its' not easily found in the literature.